# SQL Server Performance With Large Amount Of Tables In Database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, sql-server-2014

currently, we're planning a complex software architecture with a lot of entities based on Entity Framework (Code First) and MSSQL Server 2012.

One important requirement is multi language support. I decided to split each entity into two parts (variant part and invariant part). So for each entity we'll get two tables in database.

My question is: Do you see any performance issues, if we double the amount of the tables in the database? In the worst case, maybe we would get between 1000 or 2000 tables.

Thanks for your help :-)

Greetings,

Patrick

Comment: Perf in terms of Code Generation time? Then have a look at the "EF Reverse POCO Templates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I heard: You can see if a database is a good one on the number of tables. The more, the better :-) Well, for sure this is not true by any means , but - as long as you keep the thing togehter - there's nothing against many tables. I would think about the "each entity" phrase... variant data is difficult to handle later. You should know before, **where** you want an open design... One suggestion: Add some XML columns to your tables for variant data. That could make it easier...